# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string on stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I have 2 similar stored procedures, but for some reason one of them works while converting into date format from string, but the other doesn't:

This is the one that doesn't work:

```
exec Search_PR 'US00000001','PR00000001', '01/01/0001', '01/01/0001', 'WH00000001', 'ST00000001','Requested'
```

Code:

```
Create Procedure Search_PR 
    (@usersID CHAR(10),
     @prNo VARCHAR(20), 
     @prDateFrom Date, 
     @prDateTo Date, 
     @warehouseID CHAR(10), 
     @storageID CHAR(10), 
     @status VARCHAR(20)
   )
As
Begin
    --some other codes
    Select * 
    From PurchaseReturn pr, storage s, warehouse w, Users u 
    Where pr.storageID = s.storageID 
      and s.warehouseID = w.warehouseID 
      and w.usersID = u.usersID 
      and u.usersID = @usersID 
      and ((pr.prNo like '%' + @prNo + '%') or @prNo Is Null) 
      and (pr.prDate >= @prDateFrom Or @prDateFrom Is Null) 
      and (pr.prDate <= @prDateTo Or @prDateTo Is Null) 
      and (w.warehouseID = @warehouseID or @warehouseID Is Null) 
      and (pr.storageID = @storageID or @storageID Is Null) 
      and (pr.status = @status Or @status Is Null)
End
```

I get this error from the above procedure:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is the procedure that works which does not throw that same error:

```
exec Search_PO 'US00000001','PO00000001','01/01/2017','01/01/0001','--Select--'

exec Search_PO 'US00000001','1','01/01/0001','01/01/0001','--Select--'
```

Code:

```
Create Procedure Search_PO
    (@usersID CHAR(10), 
     @poNo VARCHAR(20), 
     @poDate Date, 
     @poDeliveryDate Date, 
     @status VARCHAR(20)
    )
As
Begin
    --some other codes

    Select * 
    From PurchaseOrder p, Users u, Warehouse w 
    Where p.warehouseID = w.warehouseID 
      and w.usersID = u.usersID 
      and u.usersID = @usersID 
      and ((p.poNo like '%' + @poNo + '%') or @poNo Is Null) 
      and (p.poDate>=@poDate Or @poDate Is Null) 
      and (p.poDeliveryDate >= @poDeliveryDate Or @poDeliveryDate Is Null) 
      and (p.status = @status Or @status Is Null)
End
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join syntax is ancient and horrible.

[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Also, when specifying a string `date`, it would be better to use '00010101' for '0001-01-01'.

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)

Try explicitly converting the `pr.prDate` to `date`.

```
create procedure Search_pr(
    @usersid char(10) 
  , @prNo varchar(20)
  , @prDateFrom date
  , @prDateTo date
  , @warehouseid char(10)
  , @storageid char(10)
  , @status varchar(20)
  ) As
begin
set nocount on;
--some other codes
select *
from PurchaseReturn pr
 , storage s
 , warehouse w
 , Users u
where pr.storageid = s.storageid
  and s.warehouseid = w.warehouseid
  and w.usersid = u.usersid
  and u.usersid = @usersid
  and ((pr.prNo like '%' + @prNo + '%') or @prNo is null)
  and (convert(date,pr.prDate) >= @prDateFrom or @prDateFrom is null)
  and (convert(date,pr.prDate) <= @prDateTo or @prDateTo is null)
  and (w.warehouseid = @warehouseid or @warehouseid is null)
  and (pr.storageid = @storageid or @storageid is null)
  and (pr.status = @status or @status is null)
end;
```